# How to compare two logical expressions from SQL where condition?

Tags: java, sql, regex, complexity-theory, np

I want two compare two SQL where clauses to check if the conditions are similar.

In the below example the SQL queries have same logical conditions in the where clause. What operation shall tell me that both where clause conditions are logically same?

*Is there a REGEX for this? Any other approach?*

```
String Q3 = "select t1.ID as ID,t1.FIELD8 as I_RECHARGE_TYPE,t1.FIELD28 as I_RECHARGE_AMOUNT,t1.FIELD1 as I_ACTIVATION_DATE,t1.FIELD2 as I_MSISDN from INSTANT_CDR_0 as t1 where t1.FIELD2 = ? and ((((t1.FIELD8 IS NOT NULL  AND  t1.FIELD28 > 0) OR  DATE_FORMAT(t1.FIELD1,'%Y-%m-%d') > '2016-05-21')) or ((DATE_FORMAT(t1.FIELD1,'%Y-%m-%d') < '2015-12-03' OR ( t1.FIELD28 > 0 AND  t1.FIELD28 < 101))))";
String Q4 = "select t1.ID as ID,t1.FIELD1 as I_ACTIVATION_DATE,t1.FIELD8 as I_RECHARGE_TYPE,t1.FIELD28 as I_RECHARGE_AMOUNT,t1.FIELD2 as I_MSISDN from INSTANT_CDR_0 as t1 where t1.FIELD2 = ? and (((DATE_FORMAT(t1.FIELD1,'%Y-%m-%d') > '2016-05-21' OR ( t1.FIELD8 IS NOT NULL  AND  t1.FIELD28 > 0))) or (((t1.FIELD28 > 0 AND  t1.FIELD28 < 101) OR  DATE_FORMAT(t1.FIELD1,'%Y-%m-%d') < '2015-12-03')))";
```

How to compare `((a=2) and (b=3))` with `((b=3) and(a=2))` and figure out they're the same?

Comment: how do you want to compare them? lexicographically?

Comment: logical meaning based

Comment: pls provide expected output? test condition you want?

Comment: ((a<1)and(a-b) )
((a-b) and(a<b)) logicaly equal but  diffrence in format   i need to check logicaly

Comment: you have to implement SQL lexical analyzer, parser and interpreter to solve your task :)

Comment: Hint: never put more information into comments. Update your question instead. You want the make of people trying to help as easy as possible; not forcing them to read through all the comments.

Comment: Same condition means same result, what about comparing the result of both queries

Comment: Maybe JOOQ (http://www.jooq.org/) could be an alternative for you? I have worked once with it - the documentation says that a SQL-Condition is an subclass of a QueryPart with has an equals()-method to compare different SQL-QueryParts: http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.0.x/org/jooq/Condition.html - maybe you can give it a try to compare different expressions which have the same results. I am not sure if it will solve your problem but maybe it's worth a try.

Comment: At your example you only switch inputs (a and b), (b and a). Are there more complex transformations needed: a=b + 5, a - 5 = b?

Answer (score 2):

A simpler case would be if all the fields you had were booleans. So all the logical expressions would also be boolean expressions.

What you'd then have would be the problem of trying to find out if two boolean expressions are equivalent - that is, for every possible input they provide the same answer.

One approach to doing this might be this: Let `A` be the first expression and `B` the second expression and `A and B` the logical and of the two. For the two expressions to be equivalent `A and B` applied to all possible inputs must be true. Which means `not (A and B)` must be false for all inputs. Thus, the last problem becomes a [Boolean satisfiability problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem). This problem asks whether, for a boolean expression, there exists at least one assignment of inputs which makes it true. If there is, then you can say that the two expressions are **not equivalent** using our construction, otherwise you say they **are equivalent**.

The good news is that there's loads of tools for attacking the problem, called SAT-solvers, which are used in a ton of industrial applications (circuit design, for example).

The bad news is that the problem is [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness). So it's a **really hard one**. If the setup of the problem does not lend itself to the usual heuristics employed by SAT-solvers, you're gonna have to wait a while to get your results (perhaps till the heat death of the Universe?).

The worse news is that SAT solvers are focused on boolean problems, while you have SQL data types, which are more general problems. Developing the tooling for solving that is on you, unfortunately.

All this on top of, as others have mentioned, needing to parse the expression.

Depending on how exact you want the result to be, you can do this trick: run the two queries. If they provide the same result, say the expressions are equivalent. If not, say they aren't. What you have here is a situation where you can have false positives, but no false negatives. So, if you say two expressions aren't equivalent, then that's a **fact, you can't deny that**, because otherwise they'd have provided the same answer. But if you say they are equivalent, there's some chance they're actually not, and you got lucky with your data. If people add more data in the future in the tables, the two won't be equivalent. There's a bit of math here involved, and I won't sketch it in this answer, but, if one makes some assumptions about the input table/tables and one also has enough rows in the tables, the probability of a false positive, that is, of you saying two expressions are equivalent, when in fact they aren't, drops pretty low - exponentially so. So if you have something like 1000 rows to test these things on, you can be pretty sure that a match is good.

You could also do algebraic manipulations on the expressions, trying to bring one to the form of the other. There's a whole set of them one can apply, from boolean expressions (DeMorgan rules, associativity, Karnaugh Maps, etc.), which perhaps might help in finding an exact solution, especially if the *where* clauses are simple, but that would seem more fragile to me.

Hope this helps. Make sure to order the results of the queries, so you don't discard real matches.

Answer (score 0):

Simple/simplified approach that may not be good enough (initially I didn't see your comment about checking logically). As others pointed out, without relaxations, this problem is NP-Complete...

- Use something like [JSQLParser](https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser/wiki/Examples-of-SQL-parsing) to get a structured representation and then traverse the object model and try to compare between the conditions. I would try to make a function that compare two expression and check for equality. This function could be called recursively in case of expressions with deep nesting/parenthesizing.
- Try to use regex to split the where clause into conditions and then compare. Here you'd have to be careful with OR/AND and parenthesis... ideally, you'll want to end up with some hierarchical structure that preserve meaning of parenthesizing.

I tend to believe that the first approach would be easier as you won't have to break your neck with breaking/grouping of the conditions based on parenthesis etc.